# adf | how to display an image outside application root?

Tags: image, filesystems, oracle-adf

I'm trying to display an image which location was stored in DB. This is 
My question is, how can I display this image using af:image, where source is the specific path outside application root?

Answer (score 0):

1. Write a servlet that reads the image from the database and serves it.
2. In af:image - set the source to this servlet along with whatever key you wish to use (e.g., /myServlet?photoId=AAAAAAA)
3. Inside the servlet, make sure that you set the appropriate response headers (like expires, content-type, etc.)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

if this image accessible by http then you can just write full path to this image (or relative with some "../../" to get to the right upper level).
IDE will complain, but it will work without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

If the image location is an external URL, you can do:

```
<af:image source="http://some-address.com/someImage.jpg" id="i1" shortDesc="Hi"/>
```

Possibly you will get a warning in JDeveloper (depends on the version you're using), but if the URL exists and is not forbidden, it will work.